# How to achive LessThanOrEqual and GreaterThanOrEqual with LocalDate in Java8

Tags: java, localdate

I want to test for a date which is **Less Than or Equal to**  or **GreaterThanOrEqualTo**. 
I can't find any relevant functions in LocalDateAPI. There are **isBefore**, **isEqual** and **isAfter** .

I am adding a Day and subtracting a Day to achieve the same. Are there any better function to achieve same?

```
            boolean isGTOperator = filterOperator == OperatorEnum.GT;
            boolean isLTOperator = filterOperator == OperatorEnum.LT;
            boolean isLTEqualOperator = filterOperator == OperatorEnum.LTE;
            boolean isGTEqualOperator = filterOperator == OperatorEnum.GTE;

 if (isGTOperator ) {
                    return (myDate).isAfter(filterDate);

                } else if (isGTEqualOperator ) {
                    return (myDate).isAfter(filterDate.plusDays(1));
                }
                else if (isLTOperator ) {
                    return ( myDate).isBefore(filterDate);

                } else if (isLTEqualOperator ) {
                    return (myDate).isBefore(filterDate.minusDays(1));

                }
```

Comment: `lessThanOrEqual` is effectively the same as `!date1.isAfter(date2)`.

Comment: and similarly  `GreaterThanOrEqualTo` is `!date1.isBefore(date2)`

Comment: your code snippet does not describe much. What are `isGTOperator `, `isGTEqualOperator ` , etc? are they supposed to describe a compare operator ? if true, between which dates are supposed to be compared  ? `myDate` and `filterDate` like `isGTEqualOperator(date,filterDate)` ? your code is vague

Comment: Added the boolean bits, though I agree !date.isAfter() can be used but was hoping for some usable function. As you can see with 4 operators it might be hard to read !date1.isAfter...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use Date.compareTo(). The return value will be 0 if the dates are equal, greater than 0 if the date is after the argument date or less than 0 if the date is before the argument date. [This](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/) was a helpful reference.

Comment: Note that [`LocalDate.isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) specify the logic use a different logic than `compareTo`. So I would not call that equivalent, close enough but not equivalent ;)

Comment: If I had to check for Equal, I can just user .isEqual no need to use .compareTo. The question was how to combine to get "GreaterThanOrEqualTo"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two dates i.e date1 and date2

First Method **Date.compareTo()**

If both dates are equal than it returns **0**

If date1 is greater than date2 than it returns value greater than 0. `date1.compareTo(date2)>0`

If date1 is smaller than date2 than it returns value smaller than 0. `date1.compareTo(date2)<0`

**Second Method**  equals, before, after

These methods are working as per their name i.e.

```
if(date1.equals(date2)){System.out.println("true");}

if(date1.after(date2)){System.out.println("true");}

if(date1.before(date2)){System.out.println("true");}
```

**Note** The above methods are used to compare Date () i.e  **java.util.Date**

Comment: for java.time.LocalDate, we are using isBefore(), isAfter(), isEqual() and compareTo() methods.

Comment: If I had to check for Equal, I can just user .isEqual no need to use .compareTo. The question was how to combine to get "GreaterThanOrEqualTo"

Comment: try this if(date1.isAfter(date2) || date1.isEqual(date2)){}

Answer (score 0):

The best answer was provided in the comments from @JoeC and @Arthur. Just invert isBefore and isAfter, like so:

greaterThanOrEqualTo is effectively the same as

`!date1.isBefore(date2)`

lessThanOrEqual is effectively the same as

`!date1.isAfter(date2)`

or as a method:

```java
boolean greaterThanOrEqualTo(LocalDate date1, LocalDate date2) {
    return !date1.isBefore(date2)
}
```